# How to check if two strings have corresponding values at all indices?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, return, output

If I want to check if two words have compatible characters at an index, like vowels with vowels, and consonants with consonants, how  could that work, for example 'acab' and 'ecef' but not 'aaaa' and 'bbbb'

```
def example(word1, word2):

    output = False

    count = 0
    for index1 in range(len(word1)):
        for index2 in range(len(word2)):
            if (len(word1) == len(word2)):
                if (word1[index1] == 'aeiou')  and (word2[index2] == 'aeiou'):
                    if (word1[index1] != 'aeiou')  and (word2[index2] != 'aeiou'):
                        output = True

        count += 1

return output
```

Comment: specify an equality function for a comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is the loop structure:

```
for index1 in range(len(word1)):
    for index2 in range(len(word2)):
```

Translated into words, this says "for every character in `word1`, go through every character in `word2`".

What you really want is a single loop that goes through both words in lock-step, so you can compare corresponding elements. You can do this using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function. `zip` can be applied to any iterables, including strings, so you can do, for example:

```
for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
```

This will make `c1` and `c2` be the corresponding characters in each iteration of the loop.

The second important issue is that you check `if (len(word1) == len(word2)):` in every iteration. You don't need to do this more than once, and you should do it immediately, before any looping. If the words are not the same length, the result is `False` no matter what the contents is.

The last major issue is that you are using the `==` instead of the `in` operator to check for containment in a sequence. As a minor improvement, you can save the result of the containment checks instead of recomputing them twice:

```
v1 = (c1 in 'aeiou')
v2 = (c2 in 'aeiou')
if (v1 and v2) or not (v1 or v2):
```

Even better, remember that if *any* letter pair does not match, you can immediately return `False`, so really `if v1 != v2:` is the test you are looking for.

Putting it all together (and wrapping it in a function, so you can use it more than once):

```
def are_similar(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False
    for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
        v1 = (c1 in 'aeiou')
        v2 = (c2 in 'aeiou')
        if v1 != v2:
            return False
    return True
```

A simple test of the examples you provided:

```
are_similar('acab', 'ecef')   # True
are_similar('aaaa', 'bbbb')   # False
are_similar('hell', 'hello')  # False
```

You can shorten your function even further using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or better yet a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), coupled with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def are_similar(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False
    return all((c1 in 'aeiou') == (c2 in 'aeiou') for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2))
```

`all` will short circuit the evaluation (meaning that it will stop as soon as a `False` value is encountered). If you use a list comprehension, this will not give you much advantage since all the values will be computed up front, while with a generator, only the vaules up to the first `False` will be computed.